# PHP regular expression repeated chars

Tags: php, regex

In PHP I want to modify a string that has repeated chars by the following formula using regular expressions:

```
 1. Chars different from "r", "l", "e" repeated more than once
    consecutively should be replaced for the same char only one time. 
    Example: 
     - hungryyyyyyyyyy -> hungry.
     - hungryy -> hungry
     - speech -> speech

 2. Chars "r", "l", "e" repeated more than twice replaced for the same
    char twice. 
    Example:
     - greeeeeeat -> greeat
```

Thanks in advance
Pablo

Comment: I don't think aardvarks would be too happy with this.

Comment: Let's not start an armageddon over this, or we'll all be annihilated! We're having too much fun with this XD

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace('/(([rle])\2)\2*|(.)\3+/i', "$1$3", $string);
```

Explanation:

```
  (            # start capture group 1
    ([rle])      # match 'r', 'l', or 'e' and capture in group 2
    \2           # match contents of group 2 ('r', 'l', or 'e') again
  )            # end capture group 1 (contains 'rr', 'll', or 'ee')
  \2*          # match any number of group 2 ('r', 'l', or 'e')
|            # OR (alternation)
  (.)          # match any character and capture in group 3
  \3+          # match one or more of whatever is in group 3
```

Since group 1 and group 3 are on opposite sides of the alternation, only one of them can ever match.  If we are matching a group or 'r', 'l', or 'e' then group 1 will contain 'rr', 'll', or 'ee'.  If we are matching multiples of any other character then group 3 will contain that character.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Worked perfect!

Comment: If you change `\2*` to `\2+`, then the second part of the alternation will match `ee` and replace it with `e`.

Comment: should throw in an `i` modifier

Answer (score 0):

Welp, here's my take:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback(
  '~([^rle])(?:\1+)|([rle])(?:\2{2,})~i',
  function($m){return($m[1]!='')?$m[1]:$m[2].$m[2];},
  $content);
```